# Yii zii.widgets.CDetailView - Output an attribute as HTML code format

Tags: php, html, yii, widget, format

I want output attribute `description` as HTML code in CDetailView.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'title',
        'description' => array(
            'name' => 'description',
            'value' => html_entity_decode(CHtml::decode($model->description)),
        ),
        'price',
        'date',
    ),
));?>
```

Comment: So, i am else try this CHtml::decode($model->description), but this is not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will want to use the `:html` format:

```
'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'title',
        'description:html',
        'price',
        'date',
    ),
```

For other formats, see [CFormatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFormatter).

You can even extend CFormatter, and create your own formats.

```
<?php
class CustomFormatter extends CFormatter {

    public function formatLink($value) {
        return '<a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
    }

    public function formatBold($value) {
        return '<b>'.$value.'</b>';
    }

    public function formatArray($value) {
        return (is_array($value)) ?
            implode(', ', $value) : $value;
    }
}
```

If you extend the CFormatter, update your project's **main.php** to point to the new file:

```
// application components
'components' => array(

    'format' => array(
        'class' => 'application.extensions.CustomFormatter',
    ),

    ...
),
```

Example Usage:

```
    'title:bold',
    'website:link',
    'tags:array',
```

Comment: Or you can do it this way `array('name' => 'visible', 'type' => 'html', 'value' => ($model->visible ? 'Yes' : '<span style="color: red">No</span>')),`